# Android: How Can I display item id on toast in listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to get item id from list view after clicked on particular row.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String UserInfo = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), UserInfo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: so what is the exact issue?

Comment: Issue is I want to perform update and delete operations on long press using context menu but I have no idea how can I do it, I have idea

Comment: When a row is clicked, send the database id of the row to next screen. There you can fetch the complete details of the record using id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        ModelClass ref = (ModelClass) listview.getItemAtPosition(i);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ref.getid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Replace Model Class with Model Class name and getid according to ur model class.

Answer (score 2):

if you are creating list items using a custom adapter(loop through model) , you can get id like below. please paste some more code to get us an idea.

```
    UserInfo userInfo = (UserInfo) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), userInfo.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: what is UserInfo ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a class of "USERS" where you should have a section named "id"

```
    class USERS{
    String UserInfo;
    int Userid;
}
```

when you get the data from the database you ll have to initialiaze the id in the database to your USERS class instance

once youve done this you can get the id in onclick method:

```
 USERS User=userArraylist.getItemAtPosition(i);  //here you get the data from your instance  

 int id=User.Userid


 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

if you just want the position then
just easily:

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Id: "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```